# Meaning of "I am for it?"

Tags: idioms

I think it means "I'm for it now," meaning said person has to face up to some sort of chastisement/consequence (as they have done something wrong and will pay the price.) Is that right?

Are there other examples of this use?

Comment: It can mean, "I am in favor of it", or, perhaps, "I am in for it." Can you give us more context?

Comment: From the context OP gives, he does not mean the 'I am in favour of it' sense. [Here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-for-it) is a dictionary definition of 'be for it', which is colloquial in the UK. 'It' here is non-referential (unlike the 'it' in Susan's original given sense). 'I'm in for it [now]' is a rather older version.

Comment: @Edwin: "I'm in for it" is widely used in the US, and I believe is the only version of this expression that Americans hear.

Comment: I would have to agree with Peter Shor.  I immediately thought the OP had made a mistake and had left out the preposition _in_ in the idiomatic phrase _I'm in for it_.  I'd never heard _I'm for it_ in the sense of "Oh boy, I'm in trouble now!" until now. We're continually learning from the others across the Atlantic.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused between

> I am in for it.

vs

> I am for it.

*I am for it* means *I am in favour of it*, or *I side with it*.

For example,

- Those who are not for me are against me.
- Are you for or against gay marriage?
- If you are for it, we should act immediately

Whereas,

> I am in for it

could mean either

- I have gotten myself too deeply involved. I can't get out of it.
- I am committed to it.
- I am in deep trouble. It's my fault, I'm in for it. I'm in for the trouble.

Comment: I don't accept 'You have confused between' (see the link I posted). Are you saying that colloquial British usage is necessarily wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Edwin Ashworth gave a comment with a link to an Oxford Dictionaries entry explaining this:

> ## [be for it](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be_for_it)
>
> PHRASE
>
> *British 
>   
> informal*
>
> Be in imminent danger of punishment or other trouble.
>
> Example sentences
>
> - ‘We knew it would hurt; we knew we were for it in a big way.’
> - ‘God will get you in the end, the devil will not be able to save you from his fury, and then you will be for it.’
> - ‘Cook will be worried sick and Mrs Benson might very well have noticed my absence by now and I'll be for it when I get back.’
> - ‘‘If Sheila finds out I'll be for it,’ said Jim looking worried.’
> - ‘If you're not careful you'll have the matron in here and if she sees the state of this skirt I'm working on I'll be for it.’

As Peter Shor mentioned in the comments, many Americans are unfamilar with this British expression, and only recognize the similar "I am ***in*** for it" (with the same sense). On the other hand, Davo says "It may be regional, but I hear *I'm for it* at least monthly in and about Atlanta."

As many other people pointed out, "I am for it" can mean instead "I am in favo(u)r of it". So I would recommend not using "I am for it" to mean "I have to face up to the consequences" in a North American context, as it might confuse your listeners or make them think you have made an error.

Comment: It may be regional, but I hear *I'm for it* at least monthly in and about Atlanta.

Answer (score 0):

Not confused. Not at all.

The expression in British films is used in conversations that do NOT lead to the speaker being  in favor of the situation.

It seems to be more like the American expression "I'm in for it", meaning facing some trouble.

Just trying to it out with some folks in UK.